# Rails - updating a user returns `Couldn't find User with id=edit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In `views/users/index.html.erb` I have:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.teacher == current_user.teacher || current_user.role == "admin" %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.teacher %></td>
    <td><%= user.role %></td>
    <td><%= user.admin %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Problems', student_problems_path(user_email: user.email) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_registration_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

When you click on `Edit`, you are linked to `views/users/edit.html.erb`, which looks like this:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :teacher %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :teacher, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, when I click on `Update` and actually try to update the model, I get

```
Couldn't find User with id=edit
in app/controllers/users_controller.rb:51:in `update`
```

Here are the `update` and `edit` actions in the `UsersController`:

```
def update
    @user= User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    redirect_to(user_path)
end
```

And, if it helps, here are my routes:

```
                  root        /                              problems#new
        feedback_index POST   /feedback(.:format)            feedback#create
          new_feedback GET    /feedback/new(.:format)        feedback#new
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
  destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                       PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
     user_registration PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                 users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
              problems GET    /problems(.:format)            problems#index
                       POST   /problems(.:format)            problems#create
           new_problem GET    /problems/new(.:format)        problems#new
          edit_problem GET    /problems/:id/edit(.:format)   problems#edit
               problem GET    /problems/:id(.:format)        problems#show
                       PUT    /problems/:id(.:format)        problems#update
                       DELETE /problems/:id(.:format)        problems#destroy
            help_about GET    /help/about(.:format)          help#about
          problems_new GET    /problems/new(.:format)        problems#new
                  data        /data(.:format)                problems#data
      student_problems        /student_problems(.:format)    users#student_problems
```

Thanks for anyone that looks at this problem for me, it has been coming up a lot lately.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the wrong path. In your view change

```
edit_user_registration_path(user)
```

to

```
edit_user_path(user)
```

Comment: I had been trying that, but when I make that change, I get `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}`. I do have it in my controller though. Ill post it.

Comment: can you post your actual routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Nick is correct that you need to use edit_user_path, which routes you to Users#edit, instead of to the Devise registrations controller.

The error message you're getting indicates that the required id parameter in the edit_user_path helper is missing, which very likely means that one of your users in @users is not saved (its id is nil). To debug try something in your view like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
   USER ID = <%= user.id %>
<% end %>
```

You'll probably find that one of the values is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Nick is right. for editing user's profile there is no need to user `edit_user_registration_path(user)`.
This path is probably used when you create new user with the help of **Devise**.

Here you have to make sure you pass an id with your url to update user. It would be something like this

```
edit_user_path(@user.id)
```

or

```
{:controller=> 'user', :action => 'edit', :id => @user.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb you may have put this two lines in the wrong order :

`#routes.rb
resources :users
devise_for :users`

then calling mysite/users/edit will be routed to user controller with id 'edit'

it should be :

`#routes.rb
devise_for :users
resources :users`